# implicit declaration of function ‘getline’ warning thrown in one code, but not in another

Tags: c, input, getline

**THIS QUESTION IS NOT HOW TO REMOVE THE WARNING**

I am writing a shell. I referred this [source](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/). I used the same headers (in the same order), as he did, in my code.

When compiling his code, I do not get any warnings for **implicit declaration** of `getline`. But when I compile mine, it does get thrown.

The man page suggests to use `#define _GNU_SOURCE`, and adding that removed the warning from my code.

So why was no warning thrown for the code in the blog, as he did not use `#define _GNU_SOURCE`?

---

Here is the minimal code (I copied all the headers as I mentioned above)

```c
// #define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  ssize_t bytes_read;
  size_t input_buffer_size = 1024;
  char *user_input = (char *)malloc(input_buffer_size * sizeof(char));

  while (1)
  {
    printf("> ");
    bytes_read = getline(&user_input, &input_buffer_size, stdin);

    printf("%s\n", user_input);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the compilation process I used...

```sh
gcc -std=c11 -o bin/shell src/shell.c
```

Here is the error that I get if I leave the first line commented.

```
src/shell.c: In function ‘main’:
src/shell.c:18:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getline’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   18 |     bytes_read = getline(&user_input, &input_buffer_size, stdin);
      |                  ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Probably used a different version of the compiler.

Comment: What is different about your code?

Comment: Exactly what command line arguments did you use when you got the warning? Also, what does `cc --version | head -n1` print?

Comment: Show the code ([mcve]) as it is *in the question body*.

Comment: There's a non-standard function `getline` which non-conforming compilers may spew into standard headers. If you try to write your own function called `getline`, you must prevent the library one from existing by for example `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Or alternatively, if you want to use the pre-made `getline`, you need to compile with non-standard libraries `gcc -std=gnu11`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey even I am confused about it, as I used the same flags on the code in the blog-post. My first consideration was that some other preprocessor directives may be defining  `_GNU_SOURCE` but that cannot be the case as my own code failed to compile without warning!

Comment: @zwol `cc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Comment: @Lundin but compiling with the standard C compiler works fine if `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined. This is also the goto solution provided by the man pages. But how did the blog post code compile without warnings?

Comment: @Lundin You should know better than to tell people to use `-std=cXX`.

Comment: @zwol I believe we had that discussion before. Like it or not, not everyone is up to their knees in GNU. In fact it's pretty much _only_ the Linux devs that are stuck with it. Also, the root of all GNU (and POSIX) problems is that they made the incredibly bad call to place various non-standard functions in standard headers instead of coming up with new ones. Had they made a completely new library like pthread.h etc, there would be zero problems.

Comment: @Lundin I do recall bringing this up to you before, and I believe I said at the time that problems with `-std=cXX` are *less* likely on GNU than elsewhere, because GNU, unlike every other vendor I've had to work with, takes bug reports about this mode seriously. Also, as an educator, the trip hazard trigraphs pose for new C programmers is sufficient reason by itself for me to discourage use of the hyperconformant modes. You're free to not believe me about either of these, but I will continue to contradict anyone who recommends use of the hyperconformant modes, each time I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the person who wrote the tutorial you're referring to, did not supply any special compilation options when they were testing their code.  I see only one compilation command anywhere on that page, and it is `gcc -o main main.c`.  Thus, they got GCC's defaults, which, typically, make `getline` available on computers that have it.

You, however, used the compiler flag `-std=c11` when you compiled your code.  One of the effects of this flag is that GCC directs the C library's headers to declare **only** the functions, constants, variables, etc. that are specified by ISO C2011.  (Depending on which C library you're using, this directive may or may not have any effect — but Ubuntu uses the GNU C library, which implements it thoroughly.)  `getline` is not part of ISO C2011, so it is not declared and you get an "implicit declaration" diagnostic when you try to use it.

**Use of the hyperconformant `-std=cXX` modes is almost always a mistake.**  There are exactly three differences between `-std=cXX` and `-std=gnuXX` and none of them is desirable in practice:

1. As discussed above, it directs the headers not to declare anything that's not part of the specified revision of ISO C.  As you saw for yourself, this is almost never what you want when writing a nontrivial C program.  It also has a nasty tendency to break library headers — both third-party headers and the C library's own headers — because they are rarely, if ever, tested in this mode.
2. It disables "[system-specific predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html)" that pollute the user namespace (e.g. `linux`, `unix`, `arm`).  This is abstractly desirable but, like #1, has a nasty tendency to break library headers that are rarely, if ever, tested in this mode.
3. It *enables* [trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), which are a kludge to make C work with "national variants" of ASCII that are missing some punctuation.  These are so rarely used and cause so much practical confusion that they were actually stripped out of C++ 2017 (not C 2017, though).

To compile *your own code* with a reasonably picky level of conformance diagnostics, but not risk breaking library headers, there is a better combination of options:

```
cc -std=gnuXX -g -Og -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings
```

(Pick a suitable XX; if you have no reason to choose anything else, I'd go with 11.)  You may or may not want to add a `-D` switch for one of the `_xxx_SOURCE` [feature selection macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html); explaining how those work and how to choose one is a whole question in itself.