# Why int function works even when they're not declared first in C

Tags: c, function, return, prototype, return-type

I know that in order to use a function you must either define it above the main function or at least declare it first. However I noticed that C doesn't throw an error message if my function has a **int** or **void** return type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Answer: %d", cube(3));
    return 0;
}

int cube(int num)
{
    return num * num * num;
}
```

I'm still brand new to C could you explain why that rule doesn't affect int return type

Comment: It is due to the backward compatibility with old C Standards.

Comment: I think also gcc might not even warn you about first function after `main` but try adding more than one function without declaring it you will get errors.

Comment: Pre-C99 all “unknown” functions (i.e. functions not declared previously) were automatically assumed to return ‘int’. gcc v5+ will default to C99 but lesser version will default to the defunct C90 standard.

Comment: Save time, use a modern compiler and enable all warnings to get results like "warning: implicit declaration of function 'cube' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"

Comment: Thanks to everyone for explaining and yes it does warn me about implicit function declaration in the build log. I just didn't know why other return types show clear error while **int** doesn't, but now I know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decades ago, function types defaulted to returning an `int`. The 1990 C standard said, in clause 6.3.2.2:

> … If the expression that precedes the parenthesized argument list in a function call consists solely of an identifier, and if no declaration is visible for this identifier, the identifier is implicitly declared as if, in the innermost block containing the function call, the declaration
>
> `extern int identifier();`
>
> appeared…

Some C compilers still make provision for this, which is of dubious value in this millennium. You should request the compiler apply a more modern standard, such as by using the Clang switch `-std=c17`, as well as enabling warnings with `-Wmost` or `-Wall`, unless you have occasion to compile code that is more than a third of a century old.

Comment: Please don't tell new C programmers to use the hyperconformant `-std=cXX` modes. I go into great detail about why not [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958494/implicit-declaration-of-function-getline-warning-thrown-in-one-code-but-not-i/65984812#65984812). `-std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` is a much more practical setting.

Comment: @zwol: There is no such thing as “hyperconformance,” using standards-conforming modes is beneficial and not an impediment to professional software, and discouraging people from using them is bad engineering.

Comment: @zwol: I read your answer. It is unconvincing. GCC and Clang provide ways to use their extensions in conforming modes and good headers do to, as with feature selection macros. For those that do not, fixing them to do do should be promoted over tolerating nonconformance. And, if anybody finds themself stuck with such broken headers, they can at least isolate their use to a separate translation unit (designed to reexport a proper interface) rather than poisoning their whole project with them.

Comment: I might sympathize with your position if there were a `-fno-trigraphs`, but there isn't, and that by itself is sufficient reason not to use the hyperconformant modes, especially for beginners.