# warning: implicit declaration of the function ‘getline

Tags: c

I am getting this warning for implicit declaration of the getline function and have tried solutions found on stackoverflow, but still not getting rid of it. How can i fix this ?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
```

I am trying to compile this program on Unix and I'm getting the 'implicit declaration' error on this line:

```
 while(getline(&line, &len, faccess) != -1) {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014090/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-getline)

Comment: At a guess, you're on Windows (which lacks `getline`) or using a system that doesn't enable it for `_GNU_SOURCE`; if you're not on Windows, you might try the other option from the duplicate.

Comment: You may also want to look at [implicit declaration of function ‘getline’ warning thrown in one code, but not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65984812/364696).

Comment: @ShadowRanger i have checked the first link you shared and tried to use that, but it did not work

Comment: How about helping us out a bit and telling us what compiler you are using, what OS you are on and the command line you are attempting to use? That will keep us from guessing. When you say unix, do you mean Linux, or some BSD? Not picking on you, just waning to make sure you get the right info. If you are using `gcc`, then `gcc --version` will also help (just the version number)

Comment: Im using unix server for school and using bash. In my makefile, im compiling using gcc -std=c11

Comment: Does your Unix system declare `getline()` in `/usr/include/stdio.h`?  If it doesn't, then it probably won't appear magically (though it might be hidden in another header somewhere under `/usr/include`).  It may well be protected by conditional compilation (`#if` or variants on that).  What happens if you use `gcc -std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`?

Comment: *Which* unix? There's lots of them. But try `gnu11` instead of `c11`.

Comment: (if it's actually Linux and using glibc like most distributions do, you need `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` in strict C11 mode. (Can't remember if `_GNU_SOURCE` implies that))

Comment: Try `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`. The best solution is to avoid `getline` (or write your own version).

Comment: I may also suggest changing your makefile to enable full warnings and treat warnings as errors, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -Wshadow -std=gnu11` Don't accept code until it compiles without warning. Read and fix each one. gcc is really really good. It will tell you the exact line and column where the problem code is found. (you can learn a lot of C just by listing to what gcc is trying to tell you)